# Closure parameter of Generic type - anomaly

Tags: generics, groovy, closures

In the following code, why does Groovy seem to be ignoring the provided generic type declaration of the closure parameter in method `barMany`:

```
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic

@CompileStatic
class Main {
    static main(args) {
        FooSub foo = new FooSub()
        BarSub bar = new BarSub()
    }
}

@CompileStatic
class Foo<T> {
    void fooOne (T item) {}
    void fooMany(List<T> items) {
        items.each { T item -> fooOne(item) } // Compiles fine.
    }
}

@CompileStatic
class FooSub extends Foo<Integer> {}

@CompileStatic
class Bar<T extends Bar<T>>  {    
    void barOne (T item) {}
    void barMany(List<T> items) {

        items.each { T item -> barOne(item) } // Error:
        // Cannot find matching method Bar#barOne(java.lang.Object) !!!

        items.each { T item -> barOne(item as T) } // Error:
        // Expected parameter of type java.lang.Object but got T  !!!

        items.each { item -> barOne(item as T) } // Compiles fine - closure knows about T

    }
    void barManyMore(List<T> items) {
        for (T item in items) { // Compiles fine.
            barOne(item) }
    }
}

@CompileStatic
class BarSub extends Bar<BarSub> {}
```

**Update**:
Groovy Version: 2.4.5 JVM: 1.7.0_80 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Linux

**Update**
So there was this weird error that I haven't noticed before - *org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed* - I'll post full output:

```
~/grov/tests$ groovyc generics.groovy 
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
generics.groovy: 27: Expected parameter of type java.lang.Object but got T
 @ line 27, column 19.
        items.each { T item -> barOne(item) } // Error:
                     ^

generics.groovy: 27: [Static type checking] - Cannot find matching method Bar#barOne(java.lang.Object). Please check if the declared type is right and if the method exists.
 @ line 27, column 29.
        items.each { T item -> barOne(item) } // Error:
                               ^

generics.groovy: 30: Expected parameter of type java.lang.Object but got T
 @ line 30, column 22.
           items.each { T item -> barOne(item as T) } // Error:
                        ^

3 errors

~/grov/tests$ groovyc -v
Groovy compiler version 2.4.5
Copyright 2003-2015 The Apache Software Foundation. http://groovy-lang.org/
```

**Update**

Some more workarounds for completeness:
These workarounds seem to work:

```
    Closure c = { T item -> barOne(item) }; items.each c // See comments by @tim_yates
    items.each ( { T item -> barOne(item) } as Closure)  // Casting to closure works too!
```

The same issue also applies when a type is of a class based on generic T:

```
@CompileStatic
class Baz<T extends Baz<T>>  {
    List<T> getList() {
        return [new T(), new T()]
    }
}

@CompileStatic
class BazClient {
    void useBaz(Baz baz) {
        // baz.getList().each {Baz it -> println it} // Error
        Closure c = {Baz it -> println it}; baz.getList().each c  // works
        baz.getList().each ({Baz it -> println it} as Closure) // works
    }
}
```

Comment: Which version of groovy?

Comment: I updated - apologies.

Comment: I have no problems with this code, try restarting IDE. No idea why it says error.

Comment: @FIncio: I'm running from the command line.

Comment: changing `barMany` to `void barMany(List<T> items) { Closure c = { T it -> barOne(it) } ; items.each c }` seems to make it work for me, which makes me suspect it's a bug? If that works for you, it's worth raising an issue on the bug tracker https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY

Comment: @tim_yates: works too!

Comment: So I think `each` is not generic aware, so expects an Object, which then fails with `barOne`.  Separating them out breaks this dependency.  As you can see [from this blog post](http://melix.github.io/blog/2014/01/closure_param_inference.html), generics are a nightmare ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This was one of generics-related [bugs](http://groovy-lang.org/changelogs/changelog-2.4.6.html) which were fixed in Groovy 2.4.6.